# How to plot graphs in R for certain groups that satisfy a criteria?

Tags: r, subset, boxplot

Here's a simple dataset I made:

```
test <- data.frame(
   ID=1:10,
   group=c(3,2,1,3,3,3,4,1,3,3),
   height=c(156,167,165,187,153,172,178,191,155,189)
)
```

And a look at the how many individuals are in each group:

```
> table(test$group)
1 2 3 4 
2 1 6 1
```

Then I did a boxplot

```
boxplot(test$height~test$group)
```

[image: boxplot height by group]

As you can see group 2 and group 4 only have one individual in them.. I want to exclude them when doing the boxplot. In other words, do the plot on groups that have more than one observation?

I know the subset function, and think this might be useful, but not sure how to best apply it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform()` and `ave()` to add a column indicating how many observations are in each group and then use the `subset()` parameter to only keep those with more than 1 obs. For example

```
boxplot(height~group, 
    transform(test, groupcount=ave(ID, group, FUN=length)), 
    subset=groupcount>1)
```

[image]

Note that you can only use the `subset=` parameter of `boxplot()` when you use the formula syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I like dplyr for these sorts of things

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(group) %>%
         filter(n() > 1) %>% 
         boxplot(height~group, .)
```

Comment: you can do `boxplot(height~group, .)`

Comment: Thanks - the with was not at all necessary there.

Comment: @JesseRaab It still should be `boxplot(height~group, .)`, not `boxplot(height~group)`. The piping, the data is passed as the first parameter by default but `boxplot` needs the data.frame in the second parameter. The `.` will explicitly place the data where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
tab <- as.data.frame(table(test$group))
tab1 <- tab[which(tab$Freq > 1),]
test2 <- test[which(test$group %in% tab1$Var1),]
boxplot(test2$height~test2$group)
```